# Transaction non authorised

Tags: phantom

I discovered a transaction that was made from my phantom wallet to another adress. I specify that:
I didn't authorise this transaction
Prior to this transaction i interacted only with jup.ag site...i am sure it was not a phishy site. I placed a limit order on jup.ag at 8.44 pm.
At 9:14 I have an app interaction that I don't recognise and that I didn do. At 9.15 i see a transaction that my SOL was sent from my wallet to another wallet.
My SOL was staked with Phantom validator
My wallet adress:
8GD93f29K476nvFMniNGGgUUthW2tjGWr62qwCAqPUcS
The wallet that my SOL was sent to:
HC8gVh4hBA5h9z96vVKrXRtVvJqX8JTzYY59SDXwgior
When I search that wallet it shows that is a "dead wallet"
I contacted Phantom support but they provide support only by email and I am waiting for their answer.
Can you help me sort this out to get back my SOL?

Comment: Deadwallet.sol is just the name for system program, not something to be worried about. Seems like you approved a malicious transaction that transferred SOL to some other address. Regardless, this isn't really a place to ask for this! Hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news is you can’t recover your SOL.

Either you leaked the private key or you signed a malicious transaction.

I recommend you change your private key and move the remaining funds to a new wallet.

The [transaction](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2L9789gvFPHn5bfToYDFEwKM15TeeYBuUZ8JY6QvSLgZE1hpzSoAF6mjxKoNq5gPguLAFFHpcegGBX2b7Hf68ZQg) is just a simple transfer Sol instruction.

Be careful next time.
I’m very sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me jup.ag I never gave my secret seed to anyone its the same as metamask or any other extention metamask phantom trust wallet e.t.c hackers intercept transactions with ease stop blaming the traders its all compromised its a joke I had 10 solana from my phantom just taken scumbags all in it together.

Comment: Irrelevant to the purpose of this forum. Please contact the concerned wallet support if you face any security related issues. This stack exchange is for Solana development related questions/discussions only.